# Error caused by org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.Event class not found

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi everyone I'm new to Hibernate ,however I'm following a basic Hibernate  and everything work fine if I remove this class from the hibernate.cfg.xml
`org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.Event`

if added this class I get

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.Event`

I can't find this class in my library at my Hibernate Jar file`hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar`

does this class no longer used in Hibernate 5 ? maybe my tutorial is old ?

I'm just thinking that maybe I will need this class to follow with the tutorial .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** such package called `org.hibernate.tutorial` in the Hibernate source code, so my guess is that is something part of your tutorial or application code you've written.